# How to set an object's transparency via a Slider

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, transparency

I'm attempting to learn C#. (Working with Visual Studio 2015, as a Window Application Project)
I am trying to set the opacity of the main window via a HBar Slider.

I first assumed I would set it as an int (the value of the sidebar), and set the opacity of the window via that value.

I am having issues calling the value of the opacity for the window.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Clock
{
    public partial class root : Form
    {
        int Window_Transparency;
        public root()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void sbar_transp_001_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            sbar_transp_001.Value = Window_Transparency;
            root.equals.opacity = Windows_Transparency;
        }
    }
}
```

"root.equals.opacity" 
Gives an error:

> Error  CS0119  'object.Equals(object)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

I googled around, and found nothing that seemed relevant.

Please forgive my inexperience to what I assume is quite simple.
If somebody could point me in the proper way of setting values of objects in C#, I'd be appreciative. (Bonus points for the opacity, rather than the general syntax :D)

Comment: That looks like C# to me

Comment: You know what. xD that actually would make sense.... It is... Can you still help? or is it too different

Comment: C++ has no concept of slider bar or transparency. If you want to work in C++CLI, or whatever it's called this week, you'll find the calls are pretty much identical to their C# versions and documented on the same MSDN page.

Comment: How would one call it in c#? or is it ditto?

Comment: Opacity is a `double` ranging from 0 to 1, so passing it an `int` is going to be pretty boolean and frankly I'm not sure what's going to happen if you pass it a number that's out of range. [I even looked it up and I'm still not sure.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) Anyway, lose the `equals` (it's a function used to compare two objects) and you should be able to set opacity with something like `Window_Transparency / Max_Range_Of_Window_Transparency`.

Comment: Make sure `Max_Range_Of_Window_Transparency` is a `double` or you'll get integer math and round down to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember: Opacity ranges from 0 to 1, so, if your control varies from 0 to 100, you need:

```
 this.Opacity = (trackBar1.Value/100);
```

(suppose you're using TrackBar control).

Comment: This solved my errors, didn't do desired effect, but I am confident with some tweaking it will

Comment: I believe you need something like: root.opacity = sbar.value/100.  Tje logic is that. You must set a control to vary from 0 to 1 (if decimals are acceptable) or from 0 to 100, providing the division per 100 by yourself.

Comment: I do not think it understands the decimal as it's treating it as a Boolean/binary(on or off). I really want it so a user can specify it's transparency

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding clearly what you want to do. If the user needs only an ON/OFF settings, you need only to set the opacity to 0 or 1. But, you can provide a TrackBar slider to user set any value between 0 and 1 - but since TrackBar does not accept decimals (0.25 for instance), you need to set it from 0 to 100 and, before set opacity, to divide its value per 100.

Comment: I need it to be gradual, however it currently seems to be on/off only

Comment: Change the SIDEBAR control for a TrackBar one. You may set a scale there, for instance, 0 to 100 with steps on each 10. And where are you finding that SIDEBAR control? I can't see this here...

Comment: I've updated code since. Sorry. Will build in online enviroment and comment link

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
root.Opacity = Windows_Transparency
```

The code you posted actually would not get as far as the error you describe, because there's no member of `Form` called `equals`, nor `opacity`. C# is case-sensitive, and naming conventions for .NET objects is that all methods and properties are capitalized.

There are a number of other likely problems in your code, but you can address the error you are specifically asking about with the fix I describe.

For future reference, please make sure you include a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This includes making 100% sure the code you put in your question is a straight copy/paste from a real project.

Comment: If the value is changed to say, 50% in properties, wouldn't it have to save that somewhere within the project as part of a script? if so, where? One could theoretically change that value within the script to equal a variable's value (Like my int).

Comment: @4g0t: _"script"_ -- not sure what you're talking about, this is C#, not a scripting language. In any case, like I wrote above, there are likely many other issues in the code. But you haven't provided a good [mcve], so it's impossible to know what was simply omitted from the code in the question, and what's really missing in the actual program. As I said: my answer addresses _only_ the specific syntax error you've described...you may indeed have other issues you'll also need to deal with, having solved that one error.